# i am unable to use two different search bar in different pages please help in sorting this issue

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Here's the code. Please help me to resolve issue. I'm facing this issue,i am unable to use two different search bar in different pages please help in sorting this issue
Please check where I'm doing wrong and help me out with this.

```
` <div class="header">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Logo -->
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/layouts/site','logo' ); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Category -->
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">

                    <?php if (is_shop()) : ?>

                        <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" id="searchform" action="' . esc_url( home_url( '/'  ) ) . '">
                            <div class="search-blog">
                                <div class="input-group stylish-input-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="' . esc_html__( 'Search products...', 'adforest' ) . '" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" type="search">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <button type="submit"> <span class="fa fa-search"></span> </button>
                        </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
                            <input class="search-submit" value="'.esc_html__('Search','adforest').'" type="submit">
                        </form>

                    <? else:
                        //TOP SEARCH BAR (Custom Abhi)
                        echo do_shortcode('[top_search_short_base cats="%5B%7B%22cat%22%3A%22all%22%7D%5D" locations="%5B%7B%7D%5D"]');
                    endif;
                    ?>

                </div>
                <!-- Post Button -->
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 no-padding col-xs-12">
                    <?php
                    if( isset( $adforest_theme['ad_in_menu'] ) && $adforest_theme['ad_in_menu'] )
                    {
                        $btn_text   =   __( 'Post Ad','adforest' );
                        if( isset( $adforest_theme['ad_in_menu_text'] ) &&  $adforest_theme['ad_in_menu_text'] != "" )
                        {
                            $btn_text   =   $adforest_theme['ad_in_menu_text'];
                        }
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink( $adforest_theme['sb_post_ad_page'] ); ?>" class="btn btn-orange btn-block">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <?php echo esc_html($btn_text ); ?>
                        </a>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

you need add `<?php` in else statement not `<?`

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Logo -->
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="logo">
                    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/layouts/site','logo' ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Category -->
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">

                <?php if (is_shop()) : ?>

                    <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" id="searchform" action="' . esc_url( home_url( '/'  ) ) . '">
                        <div class="search-blog">
                            <div class="input-group stylish-input-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="' . esc_html__( 'Search products...', 'adforest' ) . '" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" type="search">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <button type="submit"> <span class="fa fa-search"></span> </button>
                    </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
                        <input class="search-submit" value="'.esc_html__('Search','adforest').'" type="submit">
                    </form>

                <?php else:
                    //TOP SEARCH BAR (Custom Abhi)
                    echo do_shortcode('[top_search_short_base cats="%5B%7B%22cat%22%3A%22all%22%7D%5D" locations="%5B%7B%7D%5D"]');
                endif;
                ?>

            </div>
            <!-- Post Button -->
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 no-padding col-xs-12">
                <?php
                if( isset( $adforest_theme['ad_in_menu'] ) && $adforest_theme['ad_in_menu'] )
                {
                    $btn_text   =   __( 'Post Ad','adforest' );
                    if( isset( $adforest_theme['ad_in_menu_text'] ) &&  $adforest_theme['ad_in_menu_text'] != "" )
                    {
                        $btn_text   =   $adforest_theme['ad_in_menu_text'];
                    }
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink( $adforest_theme['sb_post_ad_page'] ); ?>" class="btn btn-orange btn-block">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <?php echo esc_html($btn_text ); ?>
                    </a>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help this code really works :) only little modification was required for setting it up according to my requirement :)

Comment: Accept the answer if its worked